# form submission through jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jsp

here i am trying to submit a form request through jquery but i don't know why i am unable to do so it just executes the code and nothing is visible on my console.when i try to submit form normally through form action it is successful.any help is thank full.

**Jquery & jsp form:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.util.List,beans.Country,mainclasses.CountryListing" errorPage=""%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Post a property</title>
<jsp:useBean id="CNY" class="beans.Country" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/combochange.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contact_details_submit").click(function() {

       var companyname = $("#company_name").val();
       var officeaddress = $("#office_address").val();
       var countryname = $("#country_name option:selected").val();
       var statename = $("#state_name option:selected").val();
       var cityname = $("#city_name option:selected").val();
       var mobile_num = $("#mobilenum").val();
       alert(companyname+" : "+officeaddress);
        $.get("conatctDetailsInsert.jsp",
        {
        company_name : companyname,
        office_address:officeaddress,
        country_name:countryname,
        state_name:statename,
        city_name:cityname,
        mobilenum:mobile_num} ,function(data){
            alert(data);        
      });//end get         
     });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="500">
<tbody id="contact_details">
<tr>
<td>i am a 
<select>
<option>Agent/broker</option>
<option>Builder/Pvt.Ltd company</option>
</select>  
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><h3>Contact Details</h3></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>
Company Name:<input type="text" value="" id="company_name" name="company_name"/>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Office Address:<input type="text" value="" id="office_address" name="office_address"/><br>
Country:
<select id="country_name" name="country_name">
<option>-Select-</option>
<%
mainclasses.CountryListing  CNY_CL = new mainclasses.CountryListing(); 

List<Country> CNY_List=CNY_CL.getCountry();
for(int i=0; i < CNY_List.size(); i++ ){
CNY=(beans.Country)CNY_List.get(i);
%>



<option value="<%=CNY.getIdCountry() %>"><%=CNY.getCountryName() %></option>

<%} %>
</select><br>

State:<select id="state_name" name="state_name"><option></option></select><br>
City:<select id="city_name" name="city_name"><option></option></select><br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Contact Number:
<input type="tel" id="mobilenum" value="" name="mobilenum"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="submit" id="contact_details_submit" name="contact_details_submit"/>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Request handling jsp:**

```
<%@page import="beans.ConatctDetailsService"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%boolean x=false;
String company_name =request.getParameter("company_name");
String office_address =request.getParameter("office_address");
String country_name =request.getParameter("country_name");
String state_name =request.getParameter("state_name");
String city_name =request.getParameter("city_name");
String mobilenum =request.getParameter("mobilenum");
beans.ConatctDetailsService CTD = new beans.ConatctDetailsService();
CTD.setCompanyName(company_name);
CTD.setCompanyName(office_address);
CTD.setIdCountry(country_name);
CTD.setIdState(state_name);
CTD.setCity(city_name);
CTD.setMobNum(mobilenum);
x=CTD.insert();
System.out.println(x);
CTD.geterror();
if(x){
    out.println("done");
}
else{
    out.println("no");
}
%>
```

Comment: prevent default behaviour of input submit click

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an id to the form tag e.g.

```
<form id='myForm'>
```

And change to a on form submit.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myForm").on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting AJAX request to check what's happening:

```
$.ajax({
  type:'GET',
  url: 'conatctDetailsInsert.jsp',
  data: {company_name : companyname,
        office_address:officeaddress,
        country_name:countryname,
        state_name:statename,
        city_name:cityname,
        mobilenum:mobile_num},
  success: function(data) {
   console.log(data); 
  }, error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   console.log(err); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way, much cleaner.

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {

   var formData = $(this).serialize();

    $.get("conatctDetailsInsert.jsp",formData, function(data){
        alert(data);        
    });//end get      

    return false;   
 });
```